# How to join array of strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to join an array of `result = ["July"," ","1st"]` into `result = ["July 1st"].`  I also want to have the comma removed.

I have tried result.join() and result.join(",") but it didn't work. In fact, nothing changes. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you referencing the output? Those calls will not change the `result` variable. `var joined = result.join("");`

Comment: result = result[0]+result[1]+result[2]

Comment: codepen for reference-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ezBvyG

Comment: Are you sure you want a single element result array? What good does this result do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join it and put into an array...:

```
result = [result.join('')];
```

Comment: it works when I create a new variable and assign the result to it. I wonder why it didnt work this way result = result.join('');

Comment: Then just assign it to the result. I updated my answer.

Comment: I see, so we have to put the result.join('') inside a [ ] to make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify empty string in `.join` function

```
var result = ["July"," ","1st"]
result.join('') // "July 1st"
```

**EDIT:**
  and if you need output in array
  then it will

```
[result.join('')] // ["July 1st"]
```

Answer (score 0):

var b ="";

result.forEach(function(a){b = b.concat(a);});

console.log(b);

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the javascript [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function as follows:

```
var result = [result.reduce(function(previousString, currentString) {
                return previousString + currentString 
             })];
```

For a more detailed explanation of how it works, check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wl98eZpkp-c) by [Mattias Petter Johansson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304262/mattias-petter-johansson?tab=profile)